# Preparation of alkane through decarboxylation by soda lime

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, carboxylic-acids

Can we still prepare alkane through decarboxylation (using soda lime) if instead of using sodium    salt of carboxylic acid, we use the carboxylic acid directly.

Because I have always seen the equation being written like:

CH3COONa + NaOH --(CaO)(on heating)-> CH3COOH + Na2CO3

What if instead we just used: CH3COOH + NaOH --(CaO)(on heating)-> ???

What will we get then?

Comment: Yes you can  https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Carboxylic_Acids/Reactivity_of_Carboxylic_Acids/The_Decarboxylation_of_Carboxylic_Acids_and_Their_Salts

Comment: Reference for chem equation/expression formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Answer (score 2):

The decarboxylation equation is :  $$\ce{CH3COONa + NaOH -> CH4 + Na2CO3}$$ If you do want it, you can first synthesize $\ce{CH3COONa}$ from $\ce{CH3COOH + NaOH}$ just before heating it with an excess of $\ce{NaOH}$ so that the final and total reaction looks like
$$\ce{CH3COOH + 2 NaOH ->  CH4 + Na2CO3 + H2O}$$

The use of chalk $\ce{CaO}$ is not fondamental here. But if pure $\ce{NaOH}$ is used in the reaction before mixing it with acetate, $\ce{NaOH}$ will melt, flow and attack the glass of the tube used for the reaction, which will probably be destroyed by a reaction like $$\ce{2NaOH + SiO2 -> Na2SiO3 + H2O}$$ To prevent the contact between $\ce{NaOH}$ and the glass wall, a mixture $\ce{NaOH + CaO}$ is used. In this case, $\ce{NaOH}$ will not flow out of the chalk matrix. It can react with sodium acetate without touching the glass walls.